# Try/Catch exception so i can return an array value and print out an exception?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, try-catch

Hi i am writing a lottery method where the user has to enter in two numbers, n and k, as arguments. The lottery gets filled with a randomized queue that goes up to k. so if i put in k=10 the queue would hold 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. The argument n is the number of items that has to be removed randomly. so if i chose 3 then it could return 4,6,8 or it could be 1,3,10.

Now if n is greater than k it has to throw an error saying that there is not enough items in the queue to pull. So if i put n=5 and k=3, there are still 3 items in the queue but i can't select 5 from the queue because that's too many.

Now my problem is i have to return the items that are still in the queue. so n=5 and k=3 would return 1,3,2 or 2,3,1 and so forth. But i have to print an exception after i return that array. So far i am able to return the array but i can not get the try catch exception to work. Is there another method i can try that will return the array and then print out the exception after that so it looks like this:

```
%java Lottery 5 2 //calls the method with the arguments n=5 k=2
2  1    //still prints the items in the queue
java.lang.Exception: Not enough items in your queue. // returns the error as well
at Lottery.pickNumbers(Lottery.java:29) //dont pay attention to these line numbers, this was a test case given to us
at Lottery.main(Lottery.java:56)
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class Lottery{
    RandomizedQueue rq;
    Random Rnum = new Random();
    int [] Larray;

    // constructs a Lottery class
    public Lottery(){
    }


    // picks the numbers and store them in an array of integers
    // int n: number of items to pick
    // int k: maximum integer to be picked

   public int [] pickNumbers(int n, int k) throws Exception{

        rq = new RandomizedQueue();

        int [] remainQueue = new int [k];


        if(n>k) 
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=remainQueue.length;i++)
            {
                rq.enqueue(i);
            }
                for(int i=0; i<remainQueue.length;i++)
                {
                    remainQueue[i] = rq.dequeue();
                }
                return remainQueue; 
        }  





        for(int i =1;i<=k;i++)
        {
            rq.enqueue(i);
        }

        Larray = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0;i< Larray.length;i++)
        {
            Larray[i] = rq.dequeue();
        }

        return Larray;


    }



    // Do not change main().
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        if (args.length<2){
           System.out.println("Please enter your input values.");
           System.out.println("e.g. java Lottery [number of integers to pick] [Maximum integer to be picked]");
       }else{
           int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
           int k = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           Lottery l = new Lottery();
           try{
           int [] picked = l.pickNumbers(n,k);
           for (int i = 0; i< picked.length; i++){
               System.out.print(picked[i]+" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
           }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }



    } 

}
```

Comment: You want to print only exception message or full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you need to create your own custom Exception.
Follow the Steps.
-> Create an class that Extends Exception
-> write your own exceptions and handling
Say,

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
// special exception code goes here
}
```

Throw it as:

```
throw new MyException ("Something happened")

Catch as:

catch (MyException e)
{
// something
}
```

Here in your case 
    if(n

Answer (score 1):

Change your main method like below code.  In case of no exception you will get Result as expected in case of exception jut get previously populated Array and display that. In this way you will get populated result as well as exception both.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class Lottery{
    RandomizedQueue rq;
    Random Rnum = new Random();
    int [] Larray;

    // constructs a Lottery class
    public Lottery(){
    }


    // picks the numbers and store them in an array of integers
    // int n: number of items to pick
    // int k: maximum integer to be picked

   public int [] pickNumbers(int n, int k) throws Exception{

        rq = new RandomizedQueue();

        int [] remainQueue = new int [k];


        if(n>k) 
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=remainQueue.length;i++)
            {
                rq.enqueue(i);
            }
                for(int i=0; i<remainQueue.length;i++)
                {
                    remainQueue[i] = rq.dequeue();
                }
                return remainQueue; 
        }  





        for(int i =1;i<=k;i++)
        {
            rq.enqueue(i);
        }

        Larray = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0;i< Larray.length;i++)
        {
            Larray[i] = rq.dequeue();
        }

        return Larray;


    }



    // Do not change main().
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        if (args.length<2){
           System.out.println("Please enter your input values.");
           System.out.println("e.g. java Lottery [number of integers to pick] [Maximum integer to be picked]");
       }else{
           int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
           int k = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           Lottery l = new Lottery();
           try{
           int [] picked = l.pickNumbers(n,k);
           for (int i = 0; i< picked.length; i++){
               System.out.print(picked[i]+" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
           }catch (Exception e){
               int [] picked = l.Larray;
               for (int i = 0; i< picked.length; i++){
                   System.out.print(picked[i]+" ");
               }
               System.out.println();


           e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }



    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Doing it doesn't even make sense. Exceptions are used for Exceptional behaviour. From what I understand asking for more items than is in the queue, is expected behaviour (ie. You have a use case which says "return the remaining queue". Thus if you want to handle the error, you should simply do something like.

```
if (picked.length != k)
{
  System.out.println("You are attempting to choose more numbers than there are items (left) in the pool");
}
```

Alternatively since you know up front the values n and K you could simply do some input validation

```
if (k>n)
{
  System.out.println("The amount of available numbers is smaller than the amount of numbers you wish to draw.")
}
```

Also you should probably use a Set instead of an Array.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.  Complete working code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery {
    public void pickNumbers (int n, int k, List<Integer> values)
        throws Exception
    {
        RandomizedQueue <Integer> rq = new RandomizedQueue <Integer> ();

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            rq.enqueue (i);

        if (n <= k)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                values.add (rq.dequeue ());
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                values.add (rq.dequeue ());

            throw new Exception ("N > K");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt (args [0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt (args [1]);
        Lottery l = new Lottery ();
        List <Integer> picked = new ArrayList <Integer> (n);
        try
        {
            l.pickNumbers (n, k, picked);
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < picked.size (); i++){
            System.out.print (picked.get (i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static class RandomizedQueue <T> extends ArrayList <T>
    {
        private final Random r = new Random ();

        public void enqueue (T x)
        {
            add (x);
        }

        public T dequeue ()
        {
            return remove (r.nextInt(size ()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can either return value of throw Exception from a method, both can not be done at once.*

You can create custom Exception class and where you can keep your processed result and throw that if exception arise.

```
public class MyException extends Exception{
     private int[] processedResult;
     public MyException(String str,int[] result){
        this.processedResult = result;
     }
     ...
     @override
     public String toString(){
       ....
     }
}
```

...

```
public int [] pickNumbers(int n, int k) throws MyException{
    int[] larray = new int[n];
    try{
       ...
    }catch(Exception ex){
        new MyException("...",larray );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1. Create a list in `main()`
2. Pass that list to `pickNumbers()`
3. Make `pickNumbers()` return `void` and add the results to the list instead.
4. When you run into an error, throw the exception
5. In `main()`, catch the exception. The list will then contain all the results that have been computed so far.

Alternatively, write your own exception which accepts the existing results as arguments. `main()` can then read them from the exception.

Comment: I don't think that its good practice to rely on a passed parameter being changed even if an exception is thrown from the method.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: I agree but Java doesn't offer many other options which I can explain in just a few words.

Answer (score 0):

- You can create your own `Exception` type which overrides `setMessage`
- or simple instead of `e.printStackTrace()` use `e.getMessage()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't both throw an exception and return a value at the same time.

Take a step back and look at what you are trying to achieve. You need to return multiple values from your method - a list of numbers and a status - which would suggest to me returning a complex object containing these values instead of a plain `int[]`:

```
public class LotteryPick {
    public int status;
    public int[] numbers;
}

public LotteryPick pickNumbers(int n, int k) {
...
}
```

In reality I'd use a `Set<Integer>` for `numbers`, an enum for `status`, and probably getter/setters for the fields.

Alternatively, if you must throw an exception, create a custom exception class (`... extends IllegalArgumentException` ?) that also has an int[] field to hold the picked numbers. I wouldn't recommend this approach though and it's functionally equivalent to the above in any case.